# Eloquent Laravel: whereHas is not selecting the model table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

model code

```
 public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ecommerce\Product');
 }
```

Controller code

```
$inv = Inventory::where('is_deleted', 0)->with(['product', 'size','color'])->orderByDesc('id'); 



if($request->inv_filter == 'code'){
    $inv = $inv->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($request){
    $q->where('code', 'like', "%".$request->searchText."%")->get();
 });
 dd($inv);
```

> Error: inventories.product_id doesn't exist. But it actually exists. When i used $inv->toSql(). The raw sql query it gives is wrong. How to fix this?

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `inventories`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` AND `code` like `"%jean67%"`
```

Comment: can you migration of inventory table

Comment: you see in error it says `inventory` table not `inventories`. maybe try to set table name in model like `$table = 'yourTableName'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `get` in the `whereHas` closure. Try the following:

```
Inventory::with(['product', 'size', 'color'])->when($request->inv_filter === 'code', function ($builder) {
    $builder->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
        $q->where('code', 'like', "%".request()->searchText."%");
    });
})->where('is_deleted', 0)->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your raw query has problem that your query lacks JOIN Statement.

```
 SELECT * FROM products JOIN inventories WHERE products.id = 
 inventories.product_id ;
```

This query works smoothly you need to

Comment: Sir, the raw query is given by the laravel eloquent whereHas.